# Better method of declaring and calling sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I Have this sound chunk but I want to pre load most of this in the didloader and just call the         `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);`

Within the program

```
-(void)buttonpress{
                    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
                    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
                    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"chalkfreeze", CFSTR ("mp3"), NO);
                    UInt32 soundID;
                    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Proferd coding

```
-(void)viewDidloader
{
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
                    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
                    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"chalkfreeze", CFSTR ("mp3"), NO);
                    UInt32 soundID;
                    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
}

- (void)buttonpress
{
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

so something like the code above but it dosn't work and when i try to declare the soundID in the .h file it starts getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to play it anywhere without any issues. Just make soundID an instance variable.

Please refer SoundEffect class of http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328